# how to sort an ArrayList<Map<String, Any>>() with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to sort the ArrayList declared with

```
val mylist = ArrayList<Map<String, Any>>()

val current = HashMap<String, Any>()

current.put("label", "MyLabel")

current.put("pack", "MyPackage")

current.put("icon", iconData)

mylist.add(current)
```

And I want sort mylist according the item "label"

Thank you for your comments

Erhy

Comment: In the example the `mylist` contains only one element - `current`. So there is nothing to sort

Answer (score 1):

```
val sortedList = mylist.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.get("label") }))
```

I *think* that should do it. I don't have Kotlin installed on my current machine, so I can't give it a test. Regardless, it's certainly the general idea.

Comment: Looks right. Here's the repl: https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
mylist.sortBy{ it["label"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

because this was developing a flutter plugin

and I failed in kotlin

I transfered the sorting to dart where the solution was very simple:

```
allApps.sort((a, b) {
        return a['label'].toLowerCase().compareTo(b['label'].toLowerCase());
});
```